# Variance of Scala List map function

Tags: scala, function, covariance, contravariance, generic-variance

I have a question that's been bugging me.
Lists in Scala are covariant (`List[+A]`)

Let's say we have these classes:

```
class A  
class B extends A
```

The `map` function of `List[B]` takes a function `f: B => C`

But I can also use a `f: A => C`
which is a subclass of `f: B => C`
and it totally makes sense.

What I am currently confused by is that
the `map` function should accept only functions that are superclasses of the original function (since functions are contravariant on their arguments), which does not apply in the example I've given.

I know there's something wrong with my logic and I would like to enlightened.

Comment: The covariance of the type parameter of `List` has nothing to do with the parameter of `map`. `List[+T]` just tells you that for every place where a `List[A]` is required, it's okay to provide a `List[B]`as long as `B <: A`.

Comment: `map`, like any function, will accept any subtype of the required parameter type. And that's true for `Function[A, C] <: Function[B, C]` where `A <: C`.

Comment: These two statements do not contradict each other at all.

Comment: `map()` is a method that takes a parameter of type X, and, like all methods, it will accept a parameter that is a _sub-type_ of X. The fact that X is a function type doesn't change that. And if functions are contra-variant on _their_ arguments, that's of no concern to `map()`. The "accept X or sub-X" rule still applies.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I shouldn't mention about the covariance of Lists, since it was not related with my question. I was basically confused with the `flatMap` method of `Either[+A, +B]`, where the  'B' there is in covariant position and it was ok, and it seemed to me that the `flatMap` can accept functions with subclasses as parameters

Answer (score 3):

Your error lies in the assumption that `map(f: A => C)` should only accept functions that are superclasses of `A => C`.

While in reality, `map` will accept any function that is a subclass of `A => C`.

**In Scala, a function parameter can always be a subclass of the required type.**

The covariance of `A` in `List[A]` only tells you that, wherever a `List[A]` is required, you can provide a `List[B]`, as long as `B <: A`.

Or, in simpler words: `List[B]` can be treated as if it was a subclass of `List[A]`.

I have compiled a small example to explain these two behaviours:

```
class A  
class B extends A

// this means: B <: A

val listA: List[A] = List()
val listB: List[B] = List()

// Example 1: List[B] <: List[A]
// Note: Here the List[+T] is our parameter! (Covariance!)

def printListA(list: List[A]): Unit = println(list)

printListA(listA)
printListA(listB)

// Example 2: Function[A, _] <: Function[B, _]
// Note: Here a Function1[-T, +R] is our parameter (Contravariance!)

class C

def fooA(a: A): C = ???
def fooB(b: B): C = ???

listB.map(fooB)
listB.map(fooA)
```

[Try it out!](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/UbvFxek/2)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As you already suspected, you are mixing up things here.

On the one hand, you have a `List[+A]`, which tells us something about the relationships between `List[A]` and `List[B]`, given a relationship between `A` and `B`. The fact that `List` is covariant in `A` just means that `List[B] <: List[A]` when `B <: A`, as you know already know.

On the other hand, `List` exposes a method `map` to change its "contents". This method does not really care about `List[A]`, but only about `A`s, so the variance of `List` is irrelevant here. The bit that is confusing you here is that there is indeed some sub-typing to take into consideration: `map` accepts an argument (a `A => C` in this case, but it's not really relevant) and, as usual with methods and functions, you can always substitute its argument with anything that is a subtype of it. In your specific case, any `AcceptedType` will be ok, as long as `AcceptedType <: Function1[A,C]`. The variance that matters here is `Function`'s, not `List`'s.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I shouldn't mention about the covariance of Lists, since it was not related with my question. I was basically confused with the flatMap method of Either[+A, +B], where the 'B' there is in covariant position and it was ok, and it seemed to me that the flatMap can accept functions with subclasses as parameters